# Adding date in mysql with timezone

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

My query is i am adding date in my MySQL table which is now added with CURRENT TIMESTAMP or BY NOW ()... but it takes server time ... i need date/time to be added in my timezone i.e asia/calcutta.

i am trying something but it seems i doing it all wrong

```
<?php
$today = NOW();
$date = new DateTime($today, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Calcutta'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Calcutta'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
?>
```

can anybody help ??

Comment: ok i get it done ... Sorry for the question

Comment: If you are done with your question, either you can post your answer or remove the question, I believe posting the answer as it may help others.

Comment: You are right sagar !!

Comment: I was using NOW() which is a SQL function ... instead on NOW() i should use date() then it would work..